# Many system libraries in build folder when referencing .netstandard project

Tags: .net, build, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I'm referencing a `.netstandard 2.0` library/project from a `.Net framework 4.6.1` console app. After the build, there are many `System.*` libraries in the output directory. Is this something that can be controlled? I (possibly naively) thought if the 4.6.1 supports .net standard 2.0, it would not require to drag these dependencies.

Comment: only .net 4.7.2 is fully .net standard 2.0 compatible. so target to at least 4.7.2

Comment: Thx @magicandre1981. This is indeed the same problem.